# Advantages of pyramid_beaker over native pyramid session management

Tags: python, authentication, pyramid

What are the advantages of using pyramid_beaker instead of just using something like `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` for session authentication?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` only issues encrypted authentication cookies, and are not, in a technical sense, tied to sessions. You can only use this to identify, securely, that a user is still the same entity that logged in during an earlier HTTP connection. The cookie contains all the information needed to re-identify the user on every HTTP request. `AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy` cookies are compatible with the [`mod_auth_tkt` Apache module](http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/).

A `pyramid_beaker` session on the other hand, uses a cookie to tie a returning browser connection to some persistent server-side information. Using such a session allows your application to associate arbitrary data with a website visitor, that is not stored in the browser.

See [Webserver Session management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_%28computer_science%29#Web_server_session_management) on Wikipedia

Comment: What would be an example of this "arbitrary data"?

Comment: If you're implementing a wizard it's common to store intermediate data about what the user has entered and where they are at in a session. It's a convenience for avoiding storing that data in a more persistent storage like your database. It doesn't require a user to be logged in and it isn't shared across browser instances (usually).

Comment: The canonical example is a shopping cart, the state of a multi-form interaction ('wizard') is another, but basically anything that's too complex or large to be stored in a cookie will do. Do note that using server-side sessions can be a performance bottleneck (although Beaker certainly has you covered for scalability options).